# CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED: why is Tensorflow in Python/PyCharm so finicky?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

Every once in a while, I get an error like

> 2020-02-26 14:17:31.605963: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
>   2020-02-26 14:17:31.829898: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
>   2020-02-26 14:17:32.757316: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
>   2020-02-26 14:17:32.757384: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:337] Possibly insufficient driver version: 440.33.1
>   2020-02-26 14:17:32.758265: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
>   2020-02-26 14:17:32.758293: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:337] Possibly insufficient driver version: 440.33.1
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
>     (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
>        [[{{node conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
>     (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
>        [[{{node conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
>        [[dense/Sigmoid/_285]]

Then I reload PyCharm or reboot the system and everything runs as expected. And then it shows up again. What could be causing it?

Comment: Hi, @aurora, kindly provide your machine specifications,  TensorFlow version, CUDA, version, and other necessary details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED`, this issue is caused by `incorrect GPU driver` (insufficient driver version) or `wrong version of cuDNN` installed w.r.t `CUDA`.

> I reload PyCharm or reboot the system and everything runs as
>   expected. And then it shows up again.

Yes, If you reboot solve the problem for a short time, but happen again.

Without knowing Operating System, Tensorflow GPU Version, CUDA and cuDNN details it is bit difficult to suggest direct answer. However you refer below images for officially tested build configuration for windows and Linux/macOS.

***Windows:***
[image]

***Linux:***
[image]

***macOS:***
[image]

For more details please refer [Linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and [Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu)

The old GPU driver should be removed as the new version GPU driver needs to be installed.

To reinstall GPU driver:

1. Download the required GPU driver [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)
2. Remove the old version GPU driver:
   `apt purge nvidia*`
3. Restart the host
4. Install the download GPU driver
5. Reboot

For cuDNN install, please follow instructions as mentioned [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html) for Windows, MAC OS X and Linux respectively.

Comment: @aurora, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You